# Deployed SSRS not recognizing current user

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, windows-7-x64, credentials, reportserver

This issue seems to be localized to my computer because others do not experience the same issue.

> When developing in SSRS `&UserID` displays correctly but after Deploying to the ReportServer `&UserID` is reading as `NULL`

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. Because it is not happening to other users I am led to believe it has something to do with my Windows Login but really don't know where to start. All suggestions welcome

Comment: can you do a check on your ReportServer database (executionlog table), the reports executed by you is stored with which userID?

Comment: It looks like the reports are being executed by my Admin Account, which is not my standard windows login

Answer (score 0):

I found a Windows Credential here: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`

For my admin account. I'm not sure how the machine was determining when to apply those credentials or not, but by removing it I solved my issue.